# Use IN operator along with NOT LIKE considering wild card matching

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

I am having two tables.

```
TableA(% is a wild card character)

---------------
str           |
---------------
abc%          |
xyz%          |
pop%          |
---------------

TableB
--------------------
id | name | domain |
--------------------
1  | Paul | zzz.ko |
2  | John | abc.lo |
3  | Kal  | pop.cm |
--------------------
```

I want to fetch all the records from TableB where `domain` does not match with TableA `str` field( 
wild card matching).

Answer (score 2):

A crude query would look like this:

```
select * from TableB b
where not exists (select 1 from TableA a where b.domain like a.str)
```

Also, you might want to avoid using "str" as a column name.